# Identifier expected, Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to debug this simple application for an assignment, but I'm not sure why it won't compile...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DebugThree3
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String name;
      getName();
      displayGreeting(name);
   }

   public String getName(name)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter name: ");
      name = input.nextLine();
      return name;
   }

   public static void displayGreeting()
   {
      System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "!");
   }
}
```

Attempting to compile tells me an identifier is expected on line 12, public String getName(name). Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Not one. Too many problems.

Comment: Why does `getName()` take a parameter, but `displayGreeting()` doesn't?  Don't you want `String name = getName();`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `Type` of the parameter that a method accepts

```
public String getName(String name)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter name: ");
      name = input.nextLine();
      return name;
   }
```

Pass a parameter to the `getname` function in the `main` function.

Like SURESH pointed out, the `getname` function needs to be marked as `static`. Else, you will need to create an object of the class before you access the methods in it.

Comment: Also getName should be static

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to fix your program in two standard ways of doing what you're trying to do.

Currently you're not passing `name` and you probably assume it exists in scopes in which it does not.

I also moved the redundant put-something-in-a-parameter-and-return behaviour in:

```
String name = input.nextLine()
return name;
```

And only left:

```
return input.nextLine();
```

First way is passing `name` between functions as a parameter, **specifying its type**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DebugThree3
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String name = getName();
      displayGreeting(name);
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter name: ");
      return input.nextLine();
   }

   public static void displayGreeting(String name)
   {
      System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "!");
   }
}
```

Second way is having `name` as a static class member:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DebugThree3
{

   String name;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      getName();
      displayGreeting();
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter name: ");
      DebugThree3.name = input.nextLine();
   }

   public static void displayGreeting()
   {
      System.out.println("Hello, " + DebugThree3.name + "!");
   }
}
```